# Delete a document from ElasticSearch index by id

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a document in elastic search.
I am trying to implement a method where I can specify a string id to delete a document from the index using NEST client.

This is the indexed doc that I want to delete:

```
"hits":[{"_index":"movies","_type":"list","_id":"100","_score":0.6349302, "_source" : {
  "owner": "Bob",
  "tags": "Bobita",
  "title": "Movie clips of Bob"
}}
```

This is my C# code which doesn't delete the doc. It says id is NULL.

```
Uri localhost = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
            var setting = new ConnectionSettings(localhost);
            setting.SetDefaultIndex("movies");
            var client = new ElasticClient(setting);

            IDeleteResponse resp = client.Delete("100");                

            if (!resp.Found)
            {
                logger.Error("Failed to delete index with id=100");
            }
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: i know nothing about NEST, but it appears you are missing type type (list)... the key for ES is index/type/id.

Comment: Where and how do I specify the type and id? I am looking for that syntax and example. My my response below

Comment: If you look at here http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/26606126 you see DeleteById() which I don't get in my Nest client. I have Delete, DeleteIndex, DeleteByQuery() etc

Answer (score 7):

I believe the issue here is that NEST cannot properly infer the Id property of your document because you are not specifying a type.

If possible, try this instead:

```cs
client.Delete<YourMovieType>("100");
```

Comment: It did work for me, so it's at least worth trying if you have this problem.

Comment: Not working for me in NEST 5.x. It leaves the document as is.

Comment: How do you get the id?

Answer (score 2):

Using NEST 7.x on Elasticsearch 7.0, following code works:

```
 var x = _client.Delete<dynamic>(1);
```

(where 1 is '*_id*' value)

Use '*dynamic*' if you have not defined the mapping. Else I would suggest to use the actual type.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
await _elasticClient.DeleteAsync(new DeleteRequest(indexName, documentId));
```